# std::max_align_t unable to print its value

Tags: c++, mingw, mingw-w64

I am trying to print the value of std::max_align_t in MinGW64. Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstddef>

int main()
{
    printf("max allign: %d\n", alignof(std::max_align_t));
}
```

When I compile I get the below error:

```
/c/tools/mingw64/bin/c++.exe test23.cpp -Wall -ftrack-macro-expansion=0 -Werror -std=gnu++14 -Og -g3 -o test23.exe -Wl,--out-implib,test23.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
test23.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test23.cpp:6:57: error: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'long long unsigned int' [-Werror=format=]
     printf("max allign: %d\n", alignof(std::max_align_t));
                                                         ^
cc1plus.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
```

So I changed to below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstddef>

int main()
{
    printf("max allign: %llu\n", alignof(std::max_align_t));
}
```

But still I receive below error during compilation:

```
/c/tools/mingw64/bin/c++.exe test23.cpp -Wall -ftrack-macro-expansion=0 -Werror -std=gnu++14 -Og -g3 -o test23.exe -Wl,--out-implib,test23.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
test23.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test23.cpp:6:59: error: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format [-Werror=format=]
     printf("max allign: %llu\n", alignof(std::max_align_t));
                                                           ^
test23.cpp:6:59: error: too many arguments for format [-Werror=format-extra-args]
cc1plus.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
```

If I remove 'l' from the printf I get back to same error? How can I resolve the issue.

Comment: Fyi the compiler options are requesting C++11 and C++14 this might be confusing things

Comment: Thanks removed C++11 option and I am still getting the same issue i.e. with C++14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using C++ you can go with this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

int main()
{
    std::cout << alignof(std::max_align_t) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're writting C++, use the streams:

```
std::cout << "max allign: " << alignof(std::max_align_t) << "\n";
```

Or if you insist on using old C functions:

```
printf("max allign: %zu\n", alignof(std::max_align_t));
```

According to [`man printf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf), `std::size_t`'s format is [`"%zu"`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).